# MongoDB: field comparison within array of embedded documents without $unwind?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have a document containing an array of embedded documents with the same structure:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('5c41c2a3c3238118a0950a7b'),
    "subdocuments": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId('5c41c2b4c3238118a0950a7c'),
            "field1: "A",
            "field2: "A"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId('5c41c2b6c3238118a0950a7d'),
            "field1: "B",
            "field2: "C"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to compare `field1` and `field2` within the same subdocument, and project the result inside that subdocument, i.e.:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('5c41c2a3c3238118a0950a7b'),
    "subdocuments": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId('5c41c2b4c3238118a0950a7c'),
            "field1: "A",
            "field2: "A",
            "fields_equal": true
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId('5c41c2b6c3238118a0950a7d'),
            "field1: "B",
            "field2: "C",
            "fields_equal": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to do this without needing to unwind `subdocuments`. This does not work:

```
'$addFields': {
    'subdocuments.fields_equal': {
        '$eq': ['$subdocuments.field1','$subdocuments.field2']
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to do it? Or even if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

Run this Aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  '$addFields': {
    'subdocuments': {
      $map: {
        input: "$subdocuments",
        in: {
          $mergeObjects: [{
              fields_equal: { $eq: ["$$this.field1", "$$this.field2"] }
            },
            "$$this"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$subdocuments",

            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $addFields: {
                "subdocuments.fields_equal": {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $eq: ["$subdocuments.field1", "$subdocuments.field2"]
                        },
                        then: true,
                        else: false
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$_id',
                subdocuments: {
                    $addToSet: '$subdocuments'
                }
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question explicitly says without using `$unwind`